# MS SQL - 2 different range of date

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I use MS SQL, and I have in my table 2 columns. DATE and VALUE, and I want to select that in one column to display values between 2 dates and in second column to display value with different range of dates.something like:

```
SELECT value1, value2 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE (value1 = date between '2015-05-10' and '2015-09-10')
and (value2 = date between '2015-04-10' and '2015-11-01').
```

All I want is that from the same column with date extract values with different range of dates. Thank you!

Comment: please provide actual and excepted results

Comment: Maybe you want OR instead of AND

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
SELECT A.DATE, A.VALUE1, A.VALUE2
FROM (
   SELECT
      DATE,
      VALUE AS VALUE1
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE DATE BETWEEN'2015-05-10' AND '2015-09-10'
   ) AS A
FULL OUTER JOIN (
   SELECT
      DATE,
      VALUE AS VALUE1
   FROM TABLE
   WHERE DATE BETWEEN'2015-04-10' AND '2015-11-01'
   ) AS B
   ON A.DATE = B.DATE
```

Comment: Thank you Nguyen for the answer, this is right but for my case won't work, I did something like this in `Select` statement `SELECT case when date between'2015-01-01' and '2015-07-01' THEN value ELSE 0 END as 'HalfYearTotal', case when date between'2015-01-01' and '2015-12-01' THEN value ELSE 0 END) as as TOTAL `. However I will mark this answer like right answer. Thank you all who helped me

Comment: @DanPaschevici How is this response similar to your answer.... The response I posted has prompted to move your conditions from where Clause to Select statement.
Leaving everything aside, update your query to use Boolean operators like '>=' it should perform better...

Answer (score 2):

a bit unclear for me... you mean something like this -

```
SELECT value1, value2 
FROM tbl
WHERE value1 BETWEEN '2015-05-10' AND '2015-09-10'
    AND value2 BETWEEN '2015-04-10' AND '2015-11-01'
```

Answer (score 1):

Updated based on your response...
Since you are using different date values, you can extend the query!

```
 SELECT value1, value2 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (value1 >= date1 and date2 <=value1 )
AND  (value2 >= date3 and date4 <=value2 )
```

Comment: Hello, look how I want: `SELECT value1, value2 
FROM TABLE
WHERE (value1 = date between '2015-05-10' and '2015-09-10' and value2 = date between '2015-04-10' and '2015-11-01')`